# Kinect V2 Depth Frame Pixel Size

Tags: pixel, depth-buffer, kinect-v2

The kinect v2 provides a depth frame with the resolution of `512 x 424` pixels with a fov of `70.6 x 60 degrees` resulting in an average of about `7 x 7` pixels per degree. [[Source](http://smeenk.com/kinect-field-of-view-comparison/)].

However I was unable to find any kind of information about the pixel size of the depth frame, or is there any kind of method to calculate the pixel size from the given information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking how you to map size of pixels in the depth data?

The [depth coordinate system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785530.aspx) is orthogonal with it's origin and orientation at the KINECT sensor.
Basic [trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) tells us a relationship between opposite side and  adjacent side in a right angle triangle is `Tan A = a/b`, so horizontally we have `tan(FOV/2) = (FrameWidth/2)/depth`, hence `FrameWidth = 2*depth*tan(35.3)`, and so the `width of 1px = depth*2*tan(35.3)/512`, similarly the `height of 1px = depth*2*tan(30)/414`.

[image: KINECT field of view geometry]

```
const int FRAME_WIDTH = 512;
const int FRAME_HEIGHT = 424;
const float FOV_HORIZONTAL = 70.6 * PI / 180.0; // convert to radians
const float FOV_VERTICAL = 60.0 * PI / 180.0;   // convert to radians
const float HORIZONTAL_SCALING = 2 * std::tan(FOV_HORIZONTAL / 2.0) / (float)FRAME_WIDTH;
const float VERTICAL_SCALING = 2 * std::tan(FOV_VERTICAL / 2.0) / (float)FRAME_HEIGHT;
```

for each depth pixel you can compute its width and height by doing a simple scaling:

```
width = HORIZONTAL_SCALING * (float)depth;
height = VERTICAL_SCALING * (float)depth;
```

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer, can you maybe explain a little bit of your code or link to a source?

Comment: Thank you really much for the further explanation, sry for the late reply. If I understood correctly, this only works in a depth image from the Kinect, right? So if I have a depth image rendered from a Z-Buffer image, where the further a pixel is off from the center, the higher the z-value, this mechanism does not work, so firstly the pixel would have to be projected to the camera plane ?

Comment: Yes this is for the KINECT depth data which comes "pre-projected" as described in the doc page I linked.